# Input button click not working in Laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I am using Laravel Dusk for my project.In my test case click for input button element not executed. Here is my Templete

```
<input type="button" class="button-next slide8" id="next01" value="NEXT" dusk="NextButton">
```

and

```
$browser->press("@NextButton")
 ->assertSee("Spouses");
```

Comment: did you try using `click`instead of press?

Comment: tried..same issue

Comment: can you show me the code where you define $browser? did you specify the page you are visiting?

Comment: $browser->visit('/test');

Comment: Does this work in one line? `$browser->visit('test')->click("@NextButton")->assertSee('Spouses');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$browser->click(@NextButton)
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32451785)